# Markov Chains: How much steps to conclude a Transition Matrix

Tags: machine-learning, markov-process

I have just learned Markov Chains which I am using to model a real world problem. The model comprises 3 states `[a b c]`. For now I am collection data and calculating transitional probabilities:-

```
T[a][b] = #transitions from a to b / #total transitions to a
```

However I am stuck at determining the correct Transition Matrix. As I am getting more data, the matrix is changing drastically. So when do I finalize Transition Matrix? Does that mean that my data is too random and cannot be modelled or I am doing some mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect you have, or can make, a matrix of transition counts. Consider the data in each row to be draws from a multinomial distribution. Then you should be able to use [sample size calculations for the multinomial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19120/sample-size-for-a-variable-number-of-answers) to get off the ground.

It is also possible that your data is not well described by a simple Markov chain. There are some available techniques for this, e.g. [multistate modelling](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/msm/vignettes/msm-manual.pdf), but which may or may not fit your particular problem.